# Definition of vector valued function

Tags: definition, vector-analysis

I am self studying vector calculus. I saw a definition of vector valued function but couldn't understand what **P** means there.It was written that **P** belongs to set 'S' which is a subset of ℝᵐ . But my anticipation is that **P** means some multidimensional input or multidimensional vector. However can't that be some field like real field? And also I don't have any example of such functions. So I will be glad to have some examples and some clarification about the definition.

GIVEN definition in that book :

A vector valued function f:S⊆ℝᵐ→ℝⁿ with domain S⊆ℝᵐ and codomain ℝⁿ is a rule that assigns to each **P**∈S a unique f(**P**)∈ℝⁿ .

Comment: Without the full definition nobody can give an answer.

Comment: sure, just choose $m=1$.

Comment: @PaulFrost sorry I can't attach the picture so I have mentioned the whole definition.

Comment: Do you know what points in $\mathbb R^m$ and $\mathbb R^n$ look like?

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example. Suppose $m=n=2$, $S$ is the unit disk, $P = (x,y)$ is a point (vector) in $S$ and $f$ is defined as
$$
f(x,y) = (x^2+y^2, 2xy).
$$